# Is Fluidic Space a parallel universe or another dimension (or something else)?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In Star Trek: Voyager (Scorpion, Part II) Janeway and crew travel to Fluidic Space, the home of Species 8472.

**Do they reside in a parallel universe or some other dimension altogether?**

Comment: What exactly is the difference between the options you propose?

Comment: The definition of "the universe," as given to me by my high school physics teacher, is "everything, plus one."  Everything that exists (including the stuff we don't know about yet, hence +1) is part of the universe, that's why it's called the UNI-verse.  When people (on TV or otherwise) talk about parallel "universes" they really mean parallel *dimensions* and are just misusing the word "universe."

Comment: I always thought fluidic space was another dimension within the same universe. As I thought the same with Nagilum's void: same universe, different dimension (it was a "dimension" with no dimensions at all).

Answer (score 10):

Based on the fact that you need to traverse an *"interdimensional rift"* in order to get into Fluidic Space, it would seem highly likely that it's an alternate [dimension](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Mirror_universe) rather than a mere [subspace domain](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Schisms_(episode)).

> **TUVOK:** *We appear to have crossed an interdimensional rift...*

and

> **SEVEN OF NINE:** *My subspace link to the Collective has been weakened by the interdimensional rift. We cannot signal for help. We
>   are alone.* (beat) *We must construct a compliment of bio-molecular
>   warheads and modify your weapons to launch them.*